# Gradle android plugin, how to copy and load different dynamic library according to different product flavors?

Tags: android, gradle

I have an android module structured like below:

```
└─product module
└─src
    └─main
        ├─assets
        │  ├─flavor1
        │  └─flavor2
        ├─java
        └─jniLibs
            └─armeabi
```

I define two product flavor called flavor1 and flavor2 in module's build.gradle file, under the folder src/main/assets/flavor1/ and src/main/asssets/flavor2 are totally different dynamic library, e.g.: libhelper.so. They are intended for different product flavor.

My intention is to copy different dynamic library depending on product-flavor  to jniLibs/armeabi/ folder during gradle build process, is that a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a gradle task for the same.

```
task copyNativeLibs {
    Gradle gradle = getGradle()
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(":assemble(.*?)(Release|Debug)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(gradle.getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString());
    def flavor = matcher.group(1)

    if(flavor == 'flavor1') {
    copy {
        from '/yourlibrarypath'
        into 'src/main/assets/flavor1/ '
        }
    } else if() {
    ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But where should I put this task(make this task has what kind of dependency), so that it could run automatically in the gradle `assemble(.*?)(Release|Debug)` process after the product flavor is selected?

Comment: You can add this in your build.gradle and at the end of the file put this
`project.afterEvaluate {
    preBuild.dependsOn(copyNativeLibs)
}`
Then this task will be execute as part of assemble* builds.